# ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR - when running swirl

Tags: r, icu

I Keep getting this error whenever I `library(swirl)`:

> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :    ICU
>   init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR Error: package or namespace load
>   failed for ‘swirl’

1. I have reinstalled multiple versions of R multiple times.
2. Reinstalled `RTools` multiple times
3. Reset path and registry to what they were a week before when swirl was still working
4. Reinstalled Visual Studio and R Studio and still the same effect

Would be awesome to know what more I can do to eliminate this error. I am getting this error in all R environments (R Interactive, Visual Studio, R Studio); It was working properly till a week ago (not sure why it is not working now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied packages from a pre-existing working library and pasted in a new R library. Not sure which package was causing this issue - but after pasting these the issue got resolved:

1. assertthat
2. BH
3. bitops
4. colorspace
5. crayon
6. curl
7. DBI
8. dichromat
9. digest
10. dplyr
11. expsmooth
12. fma
13. forecast
14. fpp
15. fracdiff
16. ggplot2
17. gtable
18. httr
19. jsonlite
20. labeling
21. lazyeval
22. lmtest
23. magrittr
24. memoise
25. mime
26. munsell
27. openssl
28. plyr
29. praise
30. quadprog
31. R6
32. RColorBrewer
33. Rcpp
34. RcppArmadillo
35. RCurl
36. reshape
37. reshape2
38. scales
39. stringi
40. stringr
41. swirl
42. testthat
43. tibble
44. timeDate
45. tseries
46. yaml
47. zoo

Comment: `stringi` wraps the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library for R... so without being able to verify this I would suggest to start with reinstalling `stringi`

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted as an aswer? That way we could vote it. Installing stringi certainly solved this issue in my case...and the answer a bunch of packages without knowing where is the problem doesn't seem to me as a solution.

Answer (score -3):

When I had this issue, loading the Plyr R package resolved it for me.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please add a more specific solution or suggestion.

Comment: @BenBolker It is not a non-answer. It provides a suggested solution for the problem.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I'm still skeptical that it will be generally useful ... I suspect that re-installing `stringi` is more generally the right answer ...

Comment: @BenBolker I totally agree the answer is not necessarily useful... however, that should be evidenced by downvoting, not delete voting :-)