# convert factor to time format in r

Tags: r, time, converters

hi i have data that looks like this :
[image]

i need to cinvert the session_start and session_end from factor  to time format . 
i tried this :

```
    sessions$session_start_text=format(sessions$session_start_text,format="%H:M:S")
```

but it converts it to string . 
is there any other option? thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you can use `as.POSIXct` or `strptime` along with `format` to convert the `factor` variable to datetime class (`POSIXlt`/`POSIXct`).

```
transform(df, session_start_text = as.POSIXct(session_start_text, format = "%T"), 
              session_end_text = as.POSIXct(session_end_text, format = "%T"))
```

---

In `lubridate`, we can use `hms` to convert the columns to `"Period"` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(session_start_text = hms(session_start_text), 
         session_end_text = hms(session_end_text))
```

Moreover, there is also `anytime::anytime()` function which helps in converting to date time values.

Comment: im trying to use lubridate but i get this error Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lubridate’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘lubridate’ was built under R version 3.5.3 
> str(sessions1)

Comment: @ElizaR I think `lubridate` was not properly installed. Try installing it on a fresh session using `install.packages("lubridate")`

Comment: @ElizaR Try installing `stringi` library according to the comments in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026485/icu-init-failed-u-file-access-error-when-running-swirl