# Loading olsrr and getting a U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR

Tags: r

This is the error message I'm getting when I try to load the package. It says it is installed but when I try to load it and use it, it doesn't work.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘olsrr’ in inDL(x,
> as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):  ICU init failed:
> U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR

Any idea?

My code:
[image: code]

Comment: Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026485/icu-init-failed-u-file-access-error-when-running-swirl)

Comment: Kindly post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just added the image of the code