# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘adegenet’

Tags: r

I have tried reinstalling the package 'but it didn't help.

How can I resolve this issue?

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘adegenet’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):ICU init failed: U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38026485/3358272 ... and I'd likely start with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026485/icu-init-failed-u-file-access-error-when-running-swirl#comment83106225_38162509) referencing `stringi` (or perhaps `stringr`).

Comment: Problem solved!Thank you !